# something wrong with wep api route

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

My registered routes mapping looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "WithActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And, controller looks like this:

```
// [Route("???????????")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetPatientProviderData([FromUri]  PatientProviderIncomingDto ppDto)
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _claimDetailService.GetPatientProviderData(ppDto.patientId, ppDto.facilityGroupId, ppDto.claimId));
    return response;
}
```

I'm making a GET call like this:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/claims/GetPatientProviderData?patientId=180&facilityGroupId=9&claimId=21
```

But, it's not hitting the URL. I was expecting it to hit the URL and that the supplied parameters get converted into DTO.

Comment: so are you getting an http error, or just an empty 'DTO' Model?

Comment: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Comment: To rule out potential issues with your routes, call to your api method directly to verify it's working as intended.  Since you didn't indicate, I assume that API method lives on a controller named 'ClaimsController' ?

Comment: What does the declaration of the ClaimsController look like?

Comment: i can call a method that returns just a string. i create that test method to check such things. it works.

Comment: it was a spell mistake :( apologies.